# Moving summons chat message results in second summons

Tags: bug, chat, super-ping

When moving old chat messages as part of a clean up, if there were any superping summons in the moved messages, the super pings are fired again.  This may be beneficial in some cases if the user hasn't seen the message yet, but if the ping has been responded to, it probably shouldn't send the ping again, particularly not on old messages that are just being cleaned up.